# Problem with file directory link in amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, api, amazon-s3

Basically I have a product registration api, and in that api in my post, I send json information to my database and upload the product image which is stored in my amazon s3 and its directory link is saved in "image_url" in the product database.

But I save the link exactly like this:

```
productModel.setImage_url("https://" + BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com" + fileName);
```

So I see that this is problematic, because I'm trying with my delete method to delete the image sent inside the database and I'm not succeeding

```
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id") UUID id) {
        Optional<ProductModel> productModelOptional = productService.findById(id);
        if (!productModelOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product not found!");
        }
        ProductModel productModel = productModelOptional.get();

        String imageUrl = productModel.getImage_url();

        try {
            DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = DeleteObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                    .key(imageUrl)
                    .build();

            s3Client.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e);
        }
        productService.delete(productModelOptional.get());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Product deleted succesfully!");
    }
}
```

I thought I might be sending the link wrong somehow, but logging into my amazon s3 and clicking on the image link itself I am taken to a page with the message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

There's something wrong and I don't know what it is

Comment: Unless the contents of `fileName` starts with a `/`, then the URL it produces will be incorrect, and if it does, that's not the key that you need to pass to the delete object request.

Comment: And what would that key be and how should it be?

Comment: It should be something like "String fileName = "/products/images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-" + file.getOriginalFilename();" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In S3 there are buckets and keys.  The key is the file name, including the "folder".  It is not the entire URL.  A key may be something like `folder1/folder2/filename.txt`.  So for your code, delete with:

```
String imageUrl = productModel.getImage_url();

// extract the file name from the imageUrl.  This may be as simple
// as finding the last forward slash or it may be something stored
// in your ProductModel object

String objectKey = ...

try {
    DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = DeleteObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
            .key(objectKey)  // delete by the key
            .build();

    s3Client.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the difference in this code... Then "productModel.setImage_url("https://" + BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com" + fileName);
" is wrong?

Comment: But why even entering the file in amazon s3 and going to the url link I still can't see the image?

Comment: No - that's your code.  The difference is that you need to have the "key" to the object to be able to delete it.  You're using a URL.  And if your bucket isn't set for HTTP hosting then the URL will not allow you to see it.  You must [configure your bucket for static hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html) for the URL method to work.  But your question was about deleting.

Comment: It should be something like "String fileName = "/products/images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-" + file.getOriginalFilename();" ?